# People involved in your job application

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

I have been in a few interviews and at the end of the interview, the interviewer will mention that he will check with his colleague and get back to me if I make it to the second round.  My question is this, the job interviewer's colleague was not present in the job interview so why does he have a say if I make it to the second round?

Answer (score 8):

There may be other interviews being done by other staff, so they need time to collaborate their results.  Sometimes its a polite way of saying "we've got a lot to think about"  or "we have more interviews to do with other people"

Interviews are important, but some companies will have one person interviewing and picking their top two or three, and another person choosing two or three based purely on the CV.   Knowledge of the candidate in the interview may skew the purely-academic selection.

Personally I've never been offered a position straight from the interview; that would be particularly rare.

Comment: also quite often the interviewer doesn't have the authority to do more than make a recommendation

Comment: Typically for technical positions in my country they do a HR and a technical interview separate, precedence is up to the company and position. In the team I work we also accepted applications, but can't all the 8 of us come to the interview for quite a lot of reasons, but we discuss applicants to make sure we are all positive that s/he will be worthful as a member and we commonly agree with the decision. In this case 2 of us go to the interview, and later we evaluate the results, so Jeffrey would face somewhat same situation.

Answer (score 2):

I've never been told straight out that that I made it to the second round while at the interview. Not a single time. I've had it alluded to and hinted at but even in cases where there were strong suggestions that they wanted me, I've gotten as many negative results as positives.

There are many reasons why an interviewer may tell you they want to ask a colleague.

- It may be a group decision or at least one where group input is necessary
- There may be thoughts and impressions the interviewer wants to discuss with someone else to see if they share that opinion.
- They may not want to tell you face to face that you're not what they want, to avoid a discussion or attempt to have their mind changed.
- Colleague could also mean "person actually doing the hiring" and telling him/her "you're going to interview with Jeffrey next week" might not be appropriate.

This list goes on and on. Don't focus on what they say as much as what they do. If you get a call, great. You shouldn't stop looking though. You've done your best now it's time to get another interview elsewhere. Keep looking until you get an actual offer.

Answer (score 1):

Usually interviewers don't like to give the feedback straight away. Especially as they need to consider their answer. You're the one on test and under pressure. They already got the job so got the time to answer to you.
My opinion is just an excuse not to answer face to face, but it doesn't mean it's a negative things.
I got jobs in the past and they didn't tell me straight away I got it.